# Checkbox activates certain radio buttons

Tags: javascript, pdf, checkbox

I am new to java scripting and I need a code for the following situation.
I have a fillable PDF form that has a column of YES/NO radio buttons named **KS, KL, G**(on each row I have 2 radio buttons grouped so that when a button is clicked the other will be disabled).
At the top of this row I have a checkbox called **CB1**.
What I want to obtain is to automatically select all NO radio buttons when I check the checkbox CB1.  And if I choose a YES radio button then this should un-checkedthe CB1 checkbox.

Thank you for your help!
Mia

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this code to your check box so that it runs on MOUSE UP:

```
if (this.getField("CB1").value == "Yes") {
    this.getField("KS").value = "NO"
    this.getField("KL").value = "NO"
    this.getField("G").value = "NO"
}
```

...and then add these bits of code to each of your YES radio buttons for MOUSE UP:

```
if (this.getField("KS").value == "YES") {
    this.getField("CB1").value = "Off"
}

if (this.getField("KL").value == "YES") {
    this.getField("CB1").value = "Off"
}

if (this.getField("G").value == "YES") {
    this.getField("CB1").value = "Off"
}
```

Obviously, each of the above three snippets has to go in a different button so that it responds to it's own value.

That should achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi chris! than kyou for your help. I tried this, but it's not working. Maybe it has to do with the way the radiobuttons are grouped? The **KS, KL, G** are a group of 2 radio buttons (one named **yes** and the second **no** - this is the radio button choice).

Comment: Hi. I tried this myself and it definitely works. The radio buttons will need to be grouped and named as you described in your question. The groups called KS needs to have two radio buttons named YES and NO, etc

Comment: I added the script to the KS group, initially I added it to each of the yes no radio buttons and this is why it didn't work. if (this.getField("KS").value == "YES") {
    this.getField("CB1").value = "Off"
}

Comment: In your comment, the yes and no are lower case, but in the code above, YES is upper case. These values are case sensitive, so it might be worth checking that they are consistent throughout your document.